# KingswaySoft Google Cloud Storage Source component missing parameter

Tags: google-cloud-storage, kingswaysoft

I cant find a solution on how to provide the missing parameter in KingswaySoft Google Cloud Storage Component Editor. Anyone

[KingswaySoft Google Cloud Storage Component Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFlZo.png)

[KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.GoogleCloudStorage.GoogleCloudStorageServiceException: Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: count (SSIS Productivity Pack, v21.1.0.1551 - DtsDebugHost, v15.0.2000.170)System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv5ma.png)

Comment: hi you should say mode detail about your question  and code or configuration

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For this particular error, we encourage you to reach out to us through our support channel so that we can have a close look.